# Как проверить есть ли совпадение в базе по id? И обновить данные если такая запись есть

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Контроллер принимает данные с формы:

```
public function actionIndex(){
        $model = new EditPrice();
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            if($model->save()){
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Данные приняты');
                return $this->refresh();
            }else{
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'что-то не так');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('index', compact('model'));
    }
```

форма во view выглядит вот так

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['id' => 'testForm']])?>
<?= $form->field($model,'org_id')->label('id организации')?>
<?= $form->field($model,'arrive_in_week')->label('Цена возврата за неделю')?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::end()?>
```

я новичок в yii2,  можете направить как сделать запись в бд, если не было совпадения по org_id
,а если такая запись есть - обновить данные?
Спасибо!

Comment: а org_id - это первчный ключ таблицы EditPrice или нет?

Comment: Нет, не первичный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придётся искать запись в БД.

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
$model = EditPrice::findOne(['org_id' => $post['org_id']]);

if (is_null($model)) {
    // что-то
} else {
    $model->load($post);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Но что-то я упускаю
`
public function actionIndex(){

        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $model = EditPrice::findOne(['org_id' => $post['org_id']]);

        if (is_null($model)) {
            $model = new EditPrice();
            if($model->load($post)){
                if($model->save()){
                   .....
            }
        } else {
            $model->load($post);
            if($model->save()){
               ....
        }
        return $this->render('index', compact('model'));
    }`
у меня в этом случае $model всегда null

Comment: Может org_id во вложенном массиве. Которая от формы

Comment: Спасибо огромное! действительно org_id был в $post['EditPrice']['org_id']